# SAS count unique observation by group

Tags: if-statement, count, sas

I am looking to figure out how many customers get their product from a certain store. The problem each prod_id can have up to 12 weeks of data for each customer. I have tried a multitude of codes, some add up all of the obersvations for each customer while others like the one below remove all but the last observation.

```
proc sort data= have; BY Prod_ID cust; run;
Data want;
Set have;
by Prod_Id cust;
if (last.Prod_Id and last.cust);
    count= +1;
run;
```

data have

```
prod_id cust week  store
1       A    7/29  ABC
1       A    8/5   ABC
1       A    8/12  ABC
1       A    8/19  ABC
1       B    7/29  ABC
1       B    8/5   ABC
1       B    8/12  ABC
1       B    8/19  ABC
1       B    8/26  ABC
1       C    7/29  XYZ
1       C    8/5   XYZ
1       F    7/29  XYZ
1       F    8/5   XYZ   
2       A    7/29  ABC
2       A    8/5   ABC
2       A    8/12  ABC
2       A    8/19  ABC
2       C    7/29  EFG
2       C    8/5   EFG
2       C    8/12  EFG
2       C    8/19  EFG
2       C    8/26  EFG
```

what i want it to look like

```
prod_id store count
1       ABC    2
1       XYZ    2
2       ABC    1
2       EFG    2
```

Comment: Curious, where did you hear this: *I am trying to use the data count function as i have heard proc SQL's count function is not accurate*. Does it regard an older SAS version? Can't see how `COUNT(DISTINCT ...))` used among many SQL engines is inaccurate. Please check: `proc sql; select store, count(distinct cust) as count_cust from mydata group by store; quit;`

Comment: When i was searching through various questions on stackoverflow and sas's community forums the idea of Proc sqls count not working for large N's came up a few times. However, as i do not know how reliable those sources were (and i trust Tom's response below more than what i read elsewhere) i will remove it from my post to avoid confusing people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, read about [if-statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000202239.htm). 
I've just edited your code to make it work:

```
proc sort data=have; 
   by prod_id store cust; 
run;

data want(drop=cust week);
   set have;
   retain count;
   by prod_id store cust;
   if (last.cust) then count=count+1;
   else if (first.prod_id or first.store) then count = 0;
   if (last.prod_id or last.store) then output;
run;
```

If you will have questions, ask.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I will read over the if-statement info more so i can avoid asking questions like this in the future. Thanks.

Comment: No need to test LAST.PROD_ID and LAST.STORE if you are already testing LAST.CUST.  By definition the last observation for a given value of PROD_ID will also be the last value of the last value of STORE within that value of  PROD_ID.  And so on to CUST nested within STORE.  The set of records where LAST.CUST is true will include the smaller set where LAST.STORE is true, which in turn will include the smaller still set of records where LAST.PROD_ID is true.

Comment: That makes sense. I originally tried with only cust but i didnt realize i will still missing some of the other logic. But yes, only using Last.Cust works perfectly as well and it looks cleaner. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

The only place where the result of the COUNT() aggregate function in SQL might be confusing is that it will not count missing values of the variable.

```
select prod_id
     , store
     , count(distinct cust) as count
     , count(distinct cust)+max(missing(cust)) as count_plus_missing
from have
group by prod_id ,store
;
```